# Creating new XML nodes if sub node exists

Tags: xslt

I've been trying to achieve the following output using XSLT but have really been struggling. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

From

```
<par>
   <run>Line one<break/>
        Line two<break/>
   </run>

   <run>Another para of text<break/>
   </run>

   <run>3rd para but no break</run>    
</par>
```

To

```
 <document>
   <para>Line one</para>
   <para>Line two</para>
   <para>Another para of text</para>
   <para>3rd para but no break</para>
 </document>
```

Thank you,

Dono

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that is push-oriented and doesn't need `<xsl:for-each>`, `<xsl:if>`, or the `self::` axis.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
     <document>
       <xsl:apply-templates />  
     </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="run/text()">
     <para>
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
     </para>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the provided XML:**

```
<par>
   <run>Line one<break/>
        Line two<break/>
   </run>

   <run>Another para of text<break/>
   </run>

   <run>3rd para but no break</run>    
</par>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<document>
  <para>Line one</para>
  <para>Line two</para>
  <para>Another para of text</para>
  <para>3rd para but no break</para>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `<run>` elements are only ever going to contain text and `<break/>` elements, and that you want to normalise whitespace and exclude `<para>` elements that would only contain whitespace (suggested by your desired output), the following should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="par">
        <document>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="run">
        <xsl:for-each select="text()">
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(self::text()) != ''">
                <para>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(self::text())"/>
                 </para>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```